# Let $(X,d)$ a metric space and $A \subset X$. $A$ is bounded if and only if $\operatorname{diam}(A)$ is finite.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Good morning, I have a problem to prove the following theorem.

**Theorem:**Let $(X,d)$ a metric space and $A \subset X$. 
 $A$ is bounded if and only if $\operatorname{diam}(A)$ is finite.

#### Prove:

> $->$ A is bounded, then exist $a \in X$ and $r>0$ such that $A\subset B(a,r)$
>   
> Then $d(a,x)<r \forall x\in A$
>   
> Then $d(x,y) : x,y \in A < d(x,a) + d(y,a) < r + r = 2r$
>   
> In consequence we have:
>   $d(x,y)\leq sup${$d(x,y):x,y \in A$}$<2r<$$\infty$.
>   
>  In other words: $\operatorname{diam}$ is finite.

I have problem with the other implication. 
If $\operatorname{diam}(A)$ is finite, then $A$ is bounded.

**I think this:**

> Suppose $A$ is not bounded.
>   
>   Then $\forall a \in X$ and $r>0$ don't happen the following: $A \subset B(a,r)$
>   
> Then $d(x,a)>r \forall x \in A$
>   
> In this step i'm stuck. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2):

Just do a direct proof:

Let $\operatorname{diam}(A)$ be finite, and define $R = \operatorname{diam}(A)+1 > 0$. Pick $a \in A$.

Then take any $x \in A$, then $d(x,a) \le \operatorname{diam}(A) < R$ (as $x,a \in A$ they are bounded by the $\sup$ of all distances between points of $A$, i.e. $\operatorname{diam}(A)$). This shows that $A \subseteq B(a,R)$ so $A$ is bounded.

Answer (score 0):

> "Then $\forall a \in X$ and $r>0$ don't happen the following: $A\subset B(a,r)$.
>   Then $d(x,a)>r \forall x \in A$."

This is not true, the negation of "$A\subset B(a,r)$" is "there exists $x\in A$ such that $x\notin B(a,r)$".

So, fixed $y\in A$, we have that for every $r>0$ there exists $x\in A$ such that $d(x,y)\geq r$. Therefore, it can't be true that
$${\rm diam}(A) = \sup\{d(x,y) : x,y\in A\} < \infty.$$